# Volume Scatter problem where the volume is offset from the model

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics, shader-nodes

I'm working on creating a planet (rendered in Eevee) and I'm experiencing a quirk while trying to create the atmosphere around it. I haven't been able to find a related post so my apologies if this is a duplicate. I've attached a screenshot from the viewport as well as my node setup. The mesh that is currently selected is the Atmosphere layer to illustrate the offsetting issue. Thank you for your help!

[image: Screenshot illustrating offsetting issue]